# JAX-WS client handle SOAPFaultException

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, soap-client

A web service I'm connecting to throws a `SOAPFaultException` for all its exceptions which means the app throws only `RuntimeExceptions`.

Using wsimport I generated the code and objects to connect and communicate with the service, it also generated the JAXB objects which represents the xml content in the `detail` element of the `SOAPFaultException`.

```
   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Soap Exception From Server</faultstring>
         <faultactor>url</faultactor>
         <detail>
            <MyResponse>
               <myID>123</myId>
               <serverName>Test</serverName>
               <error>
                  <desc>Unable to verify id</desc>
               </error>
            </MyResponse>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Wsimport generated a jaxb object called `MyResponse` with `myId`,`serverName`, `error`,`desc` as variables

I want to know how can I populate the `MyResponse` jaxb object that was generated, with the `detail` element data or do I have to navigate through the elements by node to get the values?

Comment: Not completely sure of the question; possible relation/overlap with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474994/jax-ws-soap-faults-parse-the-details-of-the-error-in-a-soapfaultexception ?

Comment: I do not know if you can have a `MyResponse` deserialized automatically but perhaps you can use a `JAXBContext` manually and give it the nodes you get from the `Fault/detail` via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474994/jax-ws-soap-faults-parse-the-details-of-the-error-in-a-soapfaultexception