# Extracting textContent from server soap fault exception

Tags: java, jax-ws, soap-client

Below is the server side exception returned to the client.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-
       ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">MerchantException</faultstring>
            <detail>Invalid Store ID</detail>
          </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'm using JAX-WS and below is my catch block.

```
catch(ServerSOAPFaultException ssfe) {
            String textContent = ssfe.getFault().getTextContent();
}
```

but I'm not able to extract the detail 'invalid store id'. Even I tried the following one as well, String detail = ssfe.getFault().getDetail().getTextContent();

Comment: Server returned xml.   <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en">MerchantException</faultstring>
        <detail>Invalid Store ID</detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: Maybe the answer here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474994/jax-ws-soap-faults-parse-the-details-of-the-error-in-a-soapfaultexception

Comment: Thanks, @mnille. In my example, I'm not receiving detail entries from the server side. How can I read the detail node in such cases?